# Why was a question on theme terminology closed?

Tags: discussion

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/67689/name-for-dates-stylized-to-the-left-on-main-page

I don't know why my question was closed. It fits within the FAQ as being related to theme development. If I want to look for and eventually develop my own themes with this style I'd like to know what, if anything, the correct term is. This may not be given as an example of questions that are allowed but it is not a question that is not allowed given the current FAQ.

**UPDATE**

Some examples of topics that have remained open making it even more confusing to me why mine was closed:

[Download WordPress.com theme: how?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/60574/download-wordpress-com-theme-how)

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1748/finding-high-quality-plugins

[Need Help Finding a Wordpress E-Commerce Plugin That Utilises Custom Post Types](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/6941/need-help-finding-a-wordpress-e-commerce-plugin-that-utilises-custom-post-types)

Comment: Its nice people are downvoting this. Tells me all I need to know about this particular exchange community's mindset.

Comment: The downvotes on meta have different meaning and indicate personal disagreement with statement in post (see http://meta.wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq#vote-differences ), in this case if question indeed fits under FAQ.

Comment: I'm aware, maybe we're too nice but on the Graphic Design exchange of which I am an active member we don't have a single meta discussion that's been downvoted.

Comment: Meta of that site currently has no question with _total_ negative score, however quite a few did receive downvotes.

Answer (score 3):

How layout types are classified is unrelated to WordPress. You can build such a layout for Joomla or Drupal too.

It might be on topic on a graphic design site or on ux. But in its essence it is more a [guessing game](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/02/lets-play-the-guessing-game/) and not welcome anywhere on the SE network.

Comment: When searching for Themes on Wordpress.com or from the Install New Themes panel there are specific classifications you have to search by. Given that as the case I disagree with it being unrelated to Theme Development and specifically Theme Development in the Wordpress realm. For example on Drupal's Theme Search there is no 1-Column, 2-Column categories. On Wordpress there is. That makes it relevant.

Answer (score 3):

Good rule of a thumb to determine if question is off topic - does it stay same question if you remove WordPress from it?

What you asked (paraphrasing) was "What is this visual element called?". Your question hadn't even had WordPress in it. That visual style is not specific, dependent, treated specially or anything else by WordPress.

As [per FAQ](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq#questions) questions that are:

> **not specific to WordPress** (even if they happen in its context)

are off topic.

I've reviewed your examples:

1. Somewhat on WordPress .com vs .org border. We tend to answer such unless they dive too far into .com support.
2. Very old question, marked as community wiki - in the past this was used in kind-of-not-question fashion. The practice has been discouraged later. I've closed it as "not constructive" just now.
3. Another quite old question. Plugin recommendations had been made off topic just recently. I've closed it as "off topic" just now.

Comment: To fall in line with (1) if I edit the question to make specific mention to wanting the information regarding Wordpress Theme directory would that then allow it be reopened?

Comment: @Ryan sure, if you edit question to bring it under scope it can be reopened (by casting reopen votes by users and/or moderator). "Close" is not final and re-working question to improve it is normal and encouraged.

Answer (score 0):

After having a look at your question, it has nothing to do with [theme-development](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/theme-development). Basically it is close to a [»shopping question«](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) as it isn't asking for advice, but more like "how do I find themes like the linked ones?".

Comment: In that link under **However** it gives an example about cameras. Not to ask what is the best but that it is okay to ask how do I tell which take low-light photos? My question isn't what is the best theme of that style but how do I tell what themes have that style.

Comment: So you're not asking "what to shop", but more "how do I shop".

Comment: See in the link of shopping questions you gave that under **However** it goes on to explain the difference is that one question's answer will remain the answer indefinitely. The question I asked I feel meets that criteria, at least until Wordpress decides to restructure how people search for themes.

Comment: I just updated the question with links to other questions of similar nature that have remained open and all have been answered and marked as answered.

Comment: All three of those questions could not be asked and answered correctly without including Wordpress. Unlike yours.

Answer (score 0):

The question is not a Wordpress specific question at all. I've seen themes for Tumblr, Blogger, Wordpress, and almost every other CMS out there that know how to use columns and indents creatively. There's no special name for anything other than the standard layouts, which can be found almost anywhere web design is discussed.